# An introduction book for analysis with the axioms of Tarski

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, book-recommendation, axioms

Briefly: Is there an introduction book for analysis with [The axioms of Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axiomatization_of_the_reals) as basis?

(I found them very elegant. And the most important thing for me is that the axioms are "obvious", not like the [standard axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach) - for example: why should we believe that $n*m=m*n$ without proof? Is it obvious that $3+3+3+3+3=5+5+5$?)